# How to get the value of Liferay input editor in a javascript variable

Tags: liferay

In my application i am using liferay-ui:input-editor .I want to get the value of input editor to a javascript variable, How to achieve that?? I have tried

```
<liferay-ui:input-editor />

<input name="<portlet:namespace />htmlCodeFromEditorPlacedHere" type="hidden" value="" />


function createPopUp(){

var url ="<%=fetchCandidateByIdForPhoneURL%>";
var type= "fetchCandidateInfo";
var candidateId = $('#candidateID').val();
var jobId = $('#JobList').val();
var text1 = $('#text1').val();
var text2 = $('#text2').val();
var text3 = $('#text3').val();
var interviewVenue = $('#interviewVenue').val();
var interviewCC = $('#interviewCC').val();
var interviewBCC =$('#interviewBCC').val();
var startDate = $('#start-date').val();
var interviewType = $('#interviewType').val(); 

var x ;


function <portlet:namespace />initEditor() {
    return '<font style="font-weight: bold">scott was here</font>';
}

function <portlet:namespace />extractCodeFromEditor() {
    var x = document.<portlet:namespace />fm.<portlet:namespace />htmlCodeFromEditorPlacedHere.value = window.<portlet:namespace />editor.getHTML();

    alert(x);
}
```

But it is showing that
       ReferenceError:      _InterviewSchedule_WAR_InterviewScheduleportlet_initEditor is not defined error. How to resolve it and get the value in a javascript variable

Comment: do you have the `<portlet:namespace />initEditor()` javascript function defined, which the `input-editor` is calling to retrieve it's value on page load?

Answer (score 1):

Given the information provided in question, it seems that the javascript initialization function is missing for `<liferay-ui:input-editor />`. As pointed out in the tutorial [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Add+HTML+Editor+to+Portlet), which OP seems to be using (juding by variable names):

> By default, the editor will call "initEditor()" to try and pre-populate the body of the editor. In this example, when the editor loads, it will have the value of "scott was here" in bold.
>
> (...)
>
> ```
>         function <portlet:namespace />initEditor() {
>             return '<font style="font-weight: bold">scott was here</font>';
>         }
> ```

Comment: And the error is the same? Are you able to verify that the function gets the exact same namespace by, e.g., using a browser's javascript console manually trying to call it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ck editor that Liferay uses will try to call the initEditor() javascript method to try and pre-populate the contents of the editor.
Therefore, you should define such a method, even if you return a blank string.

An example is given below:

```
<aui:script>
    function <portlet:namespace />initEditor() {
        return "<%= content %>";
    }
</aui:script>
```

, where content is the string variable with the content you want to pass in when the editor is loaded. If you do not want to pass initial content then simply pass a black string.